# How to graph a python frequency dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, histogram, graphing

I am trying to graph a word frequency dict I have created, the dictionary structure is like:

```
OrderedDict([('abc', 367), ('abc', 312), ('abc', 286), ('abc', 57)])
```

However when running in Jupyer Notebook with the code shown below it is coming out poorly formatted.

Any suggestions? Many thanks in advance

[image: a]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using matplotlib.

Using a [histogram](https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-histogram/) is the easiest way to do this, but `plt.hist(a)` requires a to be a list.

If you're using a dictionary, you can use `plt.bar()`:

```
plt.bar(odict.keys(), odict.values(), width)
```